# php fwrite & append to PHP function

Tags: php, regex, fopen, fwrite

I am using fopen to reach my PHP file :

```
$readFd = @fopen($file, 'r+');
```

I would like to search this file for the function call `parent::process();`
And if this exists I would then insert a new function call after this.

I have tried using preg_replace but it does not seem to match `parent::process();`
For example the result I need is this.

```
public function process() {
  parent::process();
  $this->newFunction();
}
```

Then to write the to the file I am using :

```
fwrite($readFd, $content);
```

I guess I must be missing something important with regex.
Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the php function [fgets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to read every in the file one by one until you reach the line you need. And then your pointer will be after that line where you can write your own line.

**EDIT**

I was wrong, when you write something to a file at a specific point, everything after that point is lost. So I did a little testing and came up with this:

```
$handle = fopen($file,"r+");

$lines = array();
while(($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $lines[] = $line;
    if(strpos($line, 'parent::process()')) {
        $lines[] = '$this->newFunction();';
    }
 }
 fseek($handle, 0); // reset pointer
 foreach($lines as $line) {
    fwrite($handle, $line);
 }
 fclose($handle);
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Ok thanks this is a step further :) 
I have now matched my function however I am still not sure how to write to the next line after my match.

`while(($line = fgets($readFd)) !== false) {
   if(strpos($line, "parent::process()"))
     // I want to insert after finding parent::process ???
}`

If I use fwrite it still appends to the file.

Comment: ok I am finally back to my project
and confirm your solution is simpler and it works well :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the solution however your code seems much shorter so I will try your solution tomorrow.

```
if(! $readFd = @fopen($file, "r+"))
  return FALSE;

$buffer = fread($readFd, 120000);
fclose($readFd);
$onDuplicate = FALSE;
$lines = explode("\n", $buffer);
foreach($lines AS $key => $line) {
  if(strpos($line, "newFunction()")) {
    $onDuplicate = TRUE;
  }
  if(strpos($line, "parent::process()")) {
    $lines[$key] = "\t\tparent::process();\n\t\t//\$this->newFunction();\n";
  }
}

if(! $onDuplicate) {
  $readFd = fopen($file, "w");
  $buffer = implode("\n", $lines)."\n";
  fwrite($readFd, $buffer);
  fclose($readFd);
} else {
  var_dump('changes are already applied');
}
```

Thanks for all your help!